# Rewrite simple jQuery to pure JS doesn't work. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my new project I have to do some content without jQuery. I have this jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  maxHeight = $("#container").height();
  lastSize = 9;
  while($("#content").height()<maxHeight && lastSize < 1000)
  {
      lastSize++;
    $("#content").css("font-size", lastSize);
  }
  lastSize--;
  $("#content").css("font-size", lastSize);
});
```

I'm trying to rewrite it in pure JavaScript, using this [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/from-jquery-to-javascript-a-reference/), but it hasn't worked properly :/ Here is what I got so far:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  maxHeight = document.getElementById('container').clientHeight;
  lastSize = 9;
  while(document.getElementById('content').clientHeight<maxHeight && lastSize < 1000)
  {
      lastSize++;
    document.getElementById('content').style.fontSize=lastSize;
  }
  lastSize--;
  document.getElementById('content').style.fontSize=lastSize;
});
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Sorry to hear that...

Comment: Why? Because something was ported/converted incorrectly or incompletely .. consider posting the *minimal* isolated code that does not work correctly, along with the original jQuery. (I am not going to follow those external links.)

Comment: How much are you going to pay us to do your homework for you?

Comment: We expect you to let us know what you have tried before asking us for help. It sounds like you have tried somethings (which is encouraging) but it doesn't really help us narrow down to you issue. Things you can do, are make the changes you think need to be changed, for example changing all the `$("#whatever")` to `document.getElementbyId`, and then telling us what errors you are left with when you run it without jQuery.

Comment: I'm not allowed to do it with jQuery. I think it is rewritable to JS, but my translation doesn't do, what it has to.

Comment: This is my code: http://jsbin.com/opuzur/49/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED

Please don't forget that jquery cares for cross browser compatibility.

http://jsbin.com/opuzur/51/edit

```
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(){
  if(document.readyState != "complete") return;
  container = document.getElementById('container');
  content = document.getElementById('content');
  maxHeight = container.offsetHeight;
  lastSize = 9;
  while(content.offsetHeight < maxHeight){
    content.style['font-size'] = lastSize + 'px';
    lastSize++;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Let me see usage by usage:

1) `$(document).ready(f) {}`

Replace this by the instructions in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7053197/1174076)

2) Getting an element by ID

```
maxHeight = $("#container").height();
```

you can replace for:

```
document.getElementById('container').height;
```

If `height` is not what you want investigate `clientHeight`, `offsetHeight`, etc.

3) Changing a CSS style with JS only

```
document.getElementById("content").style.fontSize="100";
```

instead of your

```
$("#content").css("font-size", lastSize);
```

Hope this helps, start small, try 2) and 3) first and then 1) if you succeed the other ones.

Comment: I tried your tips, but it still doesn't do that right. But thanks to you I know, that it doesn't depend on the "$(document).ready()" translation, because I've tried many code snippets or frameworks (not only yours, but mainly yours), but everytime it has the same output.

Comment: This the other scenarios 2) and 3) worked? You can failsafe for a simple onload but that is not 100% reliable.

Comment: Yes, 2) and 3) works great, but 1) is one of many, which doesn't work for this case. Sorry for the first comment, it could be confusing